# How to insert into table based on other one?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have these two tables:

```
 // users
+----+-------+-----------------------+--------+
| id | name  |       email           | active |
+----+-------+-----------------------+--------+
| 1  | peter | peter12@hotmail.com   | NULL   |
| 2  | jack  | most_wanted@gmail.com | NULL   |
| 3  | john  | john_20016@yahoo.com  | NULL   |
+----+-------+-----------------------+--------+

// activate
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | post_id |   random_string     |
+----+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2       | fewklw23523kf       |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

Also I have these two variables:

```
$random string = 'gergflkw4534l';
$email = 'peter12@hotmail.com';
```

And I want to insert a new row into `activate` table based on those two variables. Here is expected result:

```
// activate
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | post_id |   random_string     |
+----+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2       | fewklw23523kf       |
| 2  | 1       | gergflkw4534l       |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

As you see, I get `post_id` from `users` table based on `email` column. How can I do that?

---

```
INSERT INTO activate VALUES (null, /* I don't know */, :random_string)
INNER JOIN users ON /* I don't know */
WHERE email = :email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is very much off. You need a `WHERE` clause before you can actually `JOIN` anything to it. I'm going to assume that the `id` column in the Activate table is an autonumber column.

```
INSERT INTO Activate (post_id, random_string)
SELECT
    id,
    :random_string
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    email = :email
```

Comment: Just would it be better to I write `LIMIT 1` after `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I don't know what that would accomplish. Are you expecting the email address to match more than one row? If it does then should you only insert one Activate row? If so, how do you determine which ID to use for that insert?

Comment: No, `email` is unique, and always it matches 1 row. I said that because I think if I write `limit 1` in the end of that it will be more faster. Am I right?

Comment: That shouldn't make it any faster. You should probably have an index on the email address column if these are the kinds of queries that you'll be performing on the table. If the email address is unique then you should also have a unique key on the email column. If you had a VERY large table with NO indexing on the email column AND no unique key on the column then there might be a case where the `LIMIT 1` would run faster. In that case though, you'd have more important design problems to be worried about.

Comment: I see. Just my last question, Should I have both `unique index` and `normal index` on *email* column? Or just `unique index` is enough?

Comment: I'm not a MySQL expert, but I'm somewhat sure that a `UNIQUE KEY` on the column should suffice as MySQl will create an index for that (or they're basically synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the mysql [insert-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO activate (post_id, random_string)
SELECT id, :random_string
FROM users 
WHERE email = :email
LIMIT 1;
```